# Syntax error when upgrading Rails: unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have been using a gem called [ajaxful-rating](https://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating/blob/master/lib/axr/model.rb) for a while. Now, when I upgrade to Rails 3.1, I get the following error:

```
/Users/nn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/ajaxful_rating-2.2.9.1/lib/axr/model.rb:23: 
    syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC (SyntaxError)
/Users/nn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/ajaxful_rating-2.2.9.1/lib/axr/model.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
          options[:dimensions].each do |dimension|
```

Original code is in the link above, but the relevant part is as follow:

```
def ajaxful_rateable(options = {})
  has_many :rates_without_dimension, :as => :rateable, options.merge(:class_name => 'Rate'),
    :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => nil}
  has_many :raters_without_dimension, :through => :rates_without_dimension, :source => :rater

  options[:dimensions].each do |dimension|
    has_many "#{dimension}_rates", :dependent => :destroy,
      :conditions => {:dimension => dimension.to_s}, :class_name => 'Rate', :as => :rateable
    has_many "#{dimension}_raters", :through => "#{dimension}_rates", :source => :rater
  end if options[:dimensions].is_a?(Array)
```

What is causing this issue and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change hash syntax like below:

`:conditions => {:dimension => nil}`  TO `:conditions => [:dimension => nil]`

Can you try with above.

Means you have to change HASH syntax.